# What do people use to design the css for use with Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am going to design a site using asp.net, and after watching a tutorial to get a feel for what is will entail, it came to a point where the video just said "drop your css files into the project", so is there a common applications(s) for designing the actual css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Photoshop or Microsoft Expression.

Comment: I think the newer version of Visual Studio are CSS-friendly, but I haven't used it first-hand.

Answer (score 1):

First, learn to use a css compiler, it makes life much easier and you can write css much more intuitively in my opinion

http://compass-style.org/

Second, write css (or SASS/LESS) by hand. Designers have come a long way since the early Dreamweaver days, but in my experience, you will spend just as much time, if not more, tracking down the autogenerated stuff that doesn't work, than if you just wrote it from scratch and test with Chrome (or your other favorite in-browser CSS debugger).

Comment: Thanks Sully, that sounds very sensible.

Answer (score 1):

They could of been referring to a theme in asp.net. Creating a theme in the App_Themes folder. (ASP.Net folder when you go to the add new items)This allows you to make pathing allot simpler. You can then put your skins, images(in a image folder) along with all of your style sheets. You then can set all your pages to use that theme in a web.config file. If you use the root web.config file then it will do it for your whole site. You would link it in the  `<pages styleSheetTheme="MyTheme">`  You also will not have to have a lot of links in your head tags because all stylesheets in the theme will be inherited.(This is the drag and drop, Drag the .css file and drop it in your theme then all pages using that theme inherit the css.)  Later on you can even change your themes dynamically.

Hope this helps do what you what you where looking for if not good knowledge on how ASP.net sites work from what i have learned. I am just learning myself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an application to write css for you. Just [get yourself a book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_266239_ln?rh=n:266239,k%3acss&keywords=css&ie=UTF8&qid=1344416938&scn=266239&h=8f3009005d767a400e89704c266cac517d885f7a) on css or read some [online tutorials](http://webdesign.about.com/od/xhtml/u/htmlcssxml.htm?nl=1#s6) to get you started.

Then create one and code it yourself. That way you are in complete control of what is happening. It doesn't mean you won't spend some time tracking down strange behaviour but that is all part of the learning curve.